# Generate an array with custom index

Tags: list-manipulation, map

Apologies if this is a duplicate. I am trying (but failing) to generate the following n x n matrix in Mathematica:
[image]

where G[tj, t0] is a function along the main diagonal and G[tj, tj] is a function filling the remainder.

I'm trying to use Map, but am having difficulties specifying the arguments.

For example, using n = 5:

```
Array[g[#, #2] &, {5, 5}, {{0, 1}, {0, 1}}]
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Another possibility using a single [`Table`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Table):

```
n = 5;
Table[
    If[i==j, OverTilde[G], G][t[i], t[Mod[i-j, n]]],
    {i, 0, n-1},
    {j, 0, n-1}
] //MatrixForm //TeXForm
```

> $\left(
> \begin{array}{ccccc}
>  \tilde{G}(t(0),t(0)) & G(t(0),t(4)) & G(t(0),t(3)) & G(t(0),t(2)) & G(t(0),t(1)) \\
>  G(t(1),t(1)) & \tilde{G}(t(1),t(0)) & G(t(1),t(4)) & G(t(1),t(3)) & G(t(1),t(2)) \\
>  G(t(2),t(2)) & G(t(2),t(1)) & \tilde{G}(t(2),t(0)) & G(t(2),t(4)) & G(t(2),t(3)) \\
>  G(t(3),t(3)) & G(t(3),t(2)) & G(t(3),t(1)) & \tilde{G}(t(3),t(0)) & G(t(3),t(4)) \\
>  G(t(4),t(4)) & G(t(4),t(3)) & G(t(4),t(2)) & G(t(4),t(1)) & \tilde{G}(t(4),t(0)) \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$

Answer (score 4):

**Update:** Slightly streamlined version:

```
n = 5;
a = Array[Subscript[t, #] & /@ {##} &, {n, n}, {{0, n - 1}, {n - 1, 0}}];

m2 = MapIndexed[G @@@ RotateRight[#, #2[[1]]] &, a] /. 
       p:G[_, _[_, 0]] :> Operate[OverTilde, p]

m2 == m
```

> True

**Original answer:**

```
n = 5;
ta = Array[Subscript[t, #] &, n, 0];
tb = RotateRight[ta, #] & /@ Range[0, n - 1];
m = Apply[G, Transpose[Transpose[{ta, #}] & /@ tb], {-3}];
m = ReplacePart[m, {i_, i_} :> (m[[i, i]] /. G -> OverTilde[G])];

TeXForm @ MatrixForm @ m
```

> $\left(
> \begin{array}{ccccc}
>  \tilde{G}\left(t_0,t_0\right) & G\left(t_0,t_4\right) & G\left(t_0,t_3\right) & G\left(t_0,t_2\right) &
>    G\left(t_0,t_1\right) \\
>  G\left(t_1,t_1\right) & \tilde{G}\left(t_1,t_0\right) & G\left(t_1,t_4\right) & G\left(t_1,t_3\right) &
>    G\left(t_1,t_2\right) \\
>  G\left(t_2,t_2\right) & G\left(t_2,t_1\right) & \tilde{G}\left(t_2,t_0\right) & G\left(t_2,t_4\right) &
>    G\left(t_2,t_3\right) \\
>  G\left(t_3,t_3\right) & G\left(t_3,t_2\right) & G\left(t_3,t_1\right) & \tilde{G}\left(t_3,t_0\right) &
>    G\left(t_3,t_4\right) \\
>  G\left(t_4,t_4\right) & G\left(t_4,t_3\right) & G\left(t_4,t_2\right) & G\left(t_4,t_1\right) &
>    \tilde{G}\left(t_4,t_0\right) \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$

Answer (score 2):

Something like this?

```
Table[
 Table[G[t[j], t[k]], {k, j, 0, -1}]~Join~Table[G[t[j], t[i]], {i, n - 1, j + 1, -1}],
 {j, 0, n - 1}
]
```

For example, `n = 4`

```
{
 {G[t[0], t[0]], G[t[0], t[3]], G[t[0], t[2]], G[t[0], t[1]]}, 
 {G[t[1], t[1]], G[t[1], t[0]], G[t[1], t[3]], G[t[1], t[2]]},
 {G[t[2], t[2]], G[t[2], t[1]], G[t[2], t[0]], G[t[2], t[3]]}, 
 {G[t[3], t[3]], G[t[3], t[2]], G[t[3], t[1]], G[t[3], t[0]]}
}
```

which seems to follow the pattern.

Using nested `Table`s like this usually isn't suggested, so I'll keeping working on a better method, but for now it seems to work.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [`SparseArray`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SparseArray.html):

```
n=4;
Normal@SparseArray[
  {
    {i_,i_}->OverTilde[G][i-1,0],
    {i_,j_}->G[i-1,Mod[i-j,n]]
  },
  {n,n}
]//MatrixForm//TeXForm
```

> $$\left(
> \begin{array}{cccc}
>  \tilde{G}(0,0) & G(0,3) & G(0,2) & G(0,1) \\
>  G(1,1) & \tilde{G}(1,0) & G(1,3) & G(1,2) \\
>  G(2,2) & G(2,1) & \tilde{G}(2,0) & G(2,3) \\
>  G(3,3) & G(3,2) & G(3,1) & \tilde{G}(3,0) \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$$